# Inflating 2 Layouts on Gridview Items = CRASH :(

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-adapter

Im making a ui like in the picture:
[Sketch](http://oi62.tinypic.com/232vyc.jpg)

1. So that when i click on a gridView item it changes its contents into a Small Menu.
2. What is the right way to approach this? My solution was 2 layouts, inflate the item on click, 
   and refresh with: adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
3. It works well until you scroll down(till the item comes out of sight) and Then Crashes.
4. This is my getView() code:

   ```
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   View row = convertView;
   RecordHolder holder = null;


   Item item = data.get(position);
   LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();

   if (row == null) {

       row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
       holder = new RecordHolder();
       holder.txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_text);
       holder.imageItem = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_image);   
       row.setTag(holder);
   }
   else {
       holder = (RecordHolder) row.getTag();
   }

   if(item.showMenu == true && item.menuShown == false)
   {
       item.menuShown = true;
       row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId_menu, parent, false);
       holder = new RecordHolder();
       holder.button1 = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.button1);
       holder.button2 = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.button2);
       row.setTag(holder);
   }

   if(item.showMenu == true && item.menuShown == true)
   {
       holder.button1.setText("asdsad");
       holder.button2.setText("asdasdd");
   }

   if(item.showMenu == false && item.menuShown == true)
   {
       row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
       holder = new RecordHolder();
       holder.txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_text);
       holder.imageItem = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
       row.setTag(holder);
       holder.txtTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
       holder.imageItem.setImageBitmap(item.getImage());
   }
   if(item.showMenu == false && item.menuShown == false)
   {
       holder.txtTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
       holder.imageItem.setImageBitmap(item.getImage());
   }
   return row;
   ```

   }

No matter what i tried it keeps crashing.
Am i doing this Right?

**UPDATE**
Here is the logcat:

```
06-21 17:37:39.735    3308-3308/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.menu_grid_view_page, PID: 3308
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.menu_grid_view_page.CustomGridViewAdapter.getView(CustomGridViewAdapter.java:91)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2240)
        at android.widget.GridView.makeAndAddView(GridView.java:1345)
        at android.widget.GridView.makeRow(GridView.java:345)
        at android.widget.GridView.fillDown(GridView.java:287)
        at android.widget.GridView.fillGap(GridView.java:247)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5136)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:4247)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:781)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you post the logcat output with the crash?

Comment: I GOT IT! ILL TRY ADDING IT TO MY MESSAGE

Answer (score 0):

You are inflating two views and using only one view holder. There could be situation, when row isn't null but holder.txtTitle is null.
Instade of code:

```
if (row == null) {
..
} else {
..
}
```

try use:

```
boolean inflated = false;
if (row != null) {
    holder = (RecordHolder) row.getTag();
    if (holder.imageItem != null) {
        inflated = true;
    }
}

if(!inflated) {
    row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
    holder = new RecordHolder();
    holder.txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_text);
    holder.imageItem = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_image);   
    row.setTag(holder);
}
```

Comment: Kornel, it doesn't work. HOWEVER - SOMETHING NEW IS HAPPENING - 1. I Click an item. 2.Buttons are Showing. 3)I scroll out of visible-area. 4)WHEN I SCROLL BACK INTO VISIBLE AREA IT CRASHES. 5) Also, when you click the first Item it IMMEDIATLEY CRASH. COULD BE ARRAY OUT OF BOUNDS?